# GitLab 15 and access-tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab, access-token

When creating GitLab "Applications" for the purpose of 3rd party integrations, you also create access-tokens to enable said communication between GitLab and 3rd party software.

As of GitLab 15, access-tokens (and refresh-tokens) expire after 2hrs. GitLab seems to explain [in their docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html) that it is now expected that access-tokens (or refresh-tokens) be refreshed every 2hrs in order to keep them alive.

This means that a lot of old 3rd party integrations are now breaking in my dev environments. Is it expected that the 3rd party software now implement some cron-job or other type of scheduled job to be able to keep tokens alive?

Or should 3rd party integrations request ["Personal Access Tokens"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#when-personal-access-tokens-expire) that can have an extended lifetime, and avoid having to implement "refresh logic" for all potential customers that they support?

Comment: What type of auth flow are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [should apps] implement some cron-job or other type of scheduled job to be able to keep tokens alive?

No. While this *can work*, you *should* only create live tokens when you actually need to use them. That's why you have a refresh token -- to get new tokens after the access token expires. There's no reason to constantly keep access tokens "fresh" and available if you can generate new tokens on-demand.

Your best bet is to build this "refresh logic" into your integrated applications. The fact that tokens do not expire by default in GitLab <15 is really more of a [security bug/oversight](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21745) than a feature.

Note also that refresh tokens remain valid, even after the access token expires. Per the docs (emphasis added):

> To retrieve a new `access_token`, use the `refresh_token` parameter. **Refresh tokens may be used even after the `access_token` itself expires.** This request:
>
> - Invalidates the existing `access_token` and `refresh_token`.
> - Sends new tokens in the response.

---

> Or should 3rd party integrations request "Personal Access Tokens"

This is an option, but it's a completely different approach compared to using an OAuth application and, depending on what your integration needs, might require each individual user of your app to create a token and provide it 'manually'. The available scopes for PATs are also different than the scopes available for OAuth apps. So, it's possible, but for a number of reasons, less desirable than an OAuth application.

This might be acceptable for integrations that don't necessarily need to access resources *on behalf of* users, but can get away with a ~single token (say, a [Group Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) or a PAT belonging to a member of the customer's top-level GitLab group) or solutions where you want to enroll project-by-project using a [project token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) or similar.

However, if your integration needs to access resources *on behalf of users* or only needs access appropriate for a limited scope that is not available for access tokens (like `email` or `profile` scope),  this probably wouldn't be a good approach. You also can't make "trusted" integrations this way.

Comment: I see now that the issue is that we were working with [this deprecated pattern](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#authorization-code-flow) and that the new pattern just requires the "code_" params as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#authorization-code-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce)